# Javascript: Variables being leaked into the global scope (Firefox addon)

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, global-variables

I submitted my addon to the AMO direcotry and the editor came back with this:

```
There are still a number of variables being leaked to the global scope, 
probably because you're using them undeclared like...
```

He did not mention *all* the problem variables, is there anyway to know which are in global scope / getting leaked?

I have a crapload of variables and it would take ages going through each one of them to make sure they were declared properly with a "var".

Please help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're trying to track down variables that may have been implicitly declared as global because of the omission of `var`, you could run the code in `strict mode`. This will give you a `ReferenceError` if you try to use variables that haven't been property declared.

```
(function() {

    "use strict";   // <-- this runs code inside this function in strict mode

    // your code...

    test = 'tester';  // gives a ReferenceError

})();
```

You'll need to run it in a supported browser, like Firefox 4 or higher. The `"use strict";` declarative will ensure that any code inside the function will be evaluated using the rules of strict mode.

Comment: `use strict` is definitely the way to go. Just a note - Firefox supports block-scoped variables (replacing `var` keyword by `let` is sufficient) so wrapping your code into a function isn't necessary. Doing a search&replace changing `var` into `let` and then wrapping everything in a block (`{...}`) will do already.

Answer (score 0):

Besides properly using the var keyword, you should make sure all your javascript is wrappend in a function like this:

```
(function(){
    //Your code
}());
```

This keeps all your variables within the scope of an immediately invoked function.

Comment: Already did that, but the editor (later chatted with him on IRC) told me thats not enough

Comment: isn't the scope of an anonymous function the global scope anyway?  (self-executing or not)

Comment: @thescientist: The variable scope is not global, but the execution context will have its `this` value set to the global object unless you're in *strict mode*.

Comment: In general that holds for all functions, also named ones. Only methods have `this` bound to something else than the global object.

Answer (score 0):

Use firefox with [firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/), add a break point somewhere appropriate and *watch* the "window" object, all the variables within the global scope are a member of it.

Comment: This is for a firefox addon, am not sure if Firebug works with that, its my understanding that FB only works for non addon scripts?