# How can I detect leaking variables into a global namespace?

Tags: javascript, jslint, jshint

I have noticed a big amount of variables in my code leaked into global namespace. Is there a way to automatically find such leakages and report their position in the code?

I thought that code quality tools like jslint / jshint would be able to help me, but looking through their documentation I was not able to find anything related to this (although it looks like [it should exist](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6833855/1090562)). I was not able to find a lot of information with keywords as in my title on google. One of the few relevant findings was this post from [2009](http://perfectionkills.com/detecting-global-variable-leaks/).

Comment: A simple check may be to `Object.keys(window)` or `for..in` before your script and then do the same after and compare for any difference. Then search for those names in your code and inspect them.

Comment: Old Bookmarklet: https://github.com/kangax/detect-global

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [JSLint online tool](http://www.jslint.com/) shows you what globals are there

[image: Screenshot of JSLInt.com example]

Comment: But will 'use strict' report a lot of other problems apart from global variables?

Comment: It has nothing to do with use strict...That can be removed if you are not using it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe do something like this

```
for (var inGlobalScope in window) {
        console.log(inGlobalScope);
    }
```

Then go through the list of log entries to determine what shouldn't be in the global scope.

Comment: I already know how to find global variables, I am lookinf for a way to find where they are introduced in the code.